# get reference from parent object

Tags: python, python-3.x

is there a more efficient/pythonic way to catch a composition object upper reference. Not an heritage in terms of class but from an object that is an attribut of a parent one (array or direct).
Something like `PythonicRef(self)` in this concept sample

```
class TheChild :
   def GetParentColor( self ) :
      myVal = PythonicRef(self).Color

class TheParent :
   Color = "Red"
   AChild = TheChild()
```

actually i pass the reference in the child via a `__init__( self, MyParent )` with a object attribut in TheChild  and  `AChild = TheChild( self )` but this is heavy and using an object outside the class is loosing a bit of interest in this case because other class if very dependant.

an equivalent of super() but not for class.

In my specific case, i have a reference in a master object that use  otehr basic object from another class where this reference is used (the value, not necessary the pointer). Like the Height in a Decor object that use several object Wall that will use this Height . This could work if wall are created from the object but this is a problem if created outside than added (and height is needed for creation of a wall and can't be changed later).

Goal is not (in my case) to change parent attribute value by this way but just catch a value/function from a Parent owning the object as attribut.
Indeed dependance is that Child code assume that the specific function/attribut exist in Parent one. This is not the problem here.

Comment: "actually i pass the reference in the child via a __init__( self, MyParent ) with a object attribut in TheChild and AChild = TheChild( self ) " That is the correct way to do this. It is effective and pythonic. What else where you expecting? Stop using the terms parent/child, since that implies inheritance. In any case, because **many** can be referencing any particular object.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga how do you call the relation/link between 2 object where one is owning the second as reference ? and yes many can, this is the goal i would like to use it.

Comment: That is simply one object referencing another. In the context of a class definition/OOP, you might call it composition.

Comment: Instantiating an object only to access one attribute and discard the object immediately afterwords seems like an anti-pattern. This should probably be refactored into a function that computes a color from an instance of `TheChild`, and `PythonicRef` could use that function in its own `__init__` method to set the attribute.

Comment: @chepner I think it's just a toy example

Answer (score 1):

This would be my solution:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.color = "red"
        self.child = Child(self) #<--- reference to and creation of child, if needed
    
    def commandChild(self):
        self.child.getParentsColor()

class Child:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent # <--- reference to parent

    def getParentsColor(self):
        print(self.parent.color)

Parent().commandChild() #prints "red"
```

Edit:

the Child could edit vals of the Parent

```
def changeParentColor(self):
    self.parent.color = "green"
```

Edit2:

giving a child the Function of the Parent

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.color = "red"
        self.child = Child(self, self.sayColor) # <---

    def sayColor(self):
        print(self.color)

    def commandChild(self):
        self.child.useParentFunc()

class Child:
    def __init__(self, parent, func):
        self.color = "blue"
        self.parent = parent
        self.func = func # <--- child gets the parents func

    def useParentFunc(self):
       self.func()

Parent().commandChild()
```

maybe this is what you're looking for :)

Comment: this is teh solution i use, putting the parent reference inside the child object. Maybe the only solution because a same object can be  put in several parent object so there is ambiguity when looking up from object occurence.

Comment: mb edit2 helps :), let me know if you find a solution.